# How do I find the culprit code that is making C++ list give me 'attempting to reference a deleted function' error with MSVC 14.20.27508?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stdlist, visual-studio-2019, msvc14

I have been porting my code from Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019. It was building properly before. But now I am getting these errors:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\list(1010): error C2280: 'std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &std::pair<_Kty,_Ty>::operator =(volatile const std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function        178 114
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\list(1010): error C2280: 'std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &std::pair<_Kty,_Ty>::operator =(volatile const std::pair<_Kty,_Ty> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function        54  114
```

These errors do not refer to lines in my code, so I can't see what I have written that might cause them. And this code built without error in earlier versions of the tools.

Here are the project properties of the failing build:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/WnjmKRa]

Note: most of the projects are building fine.

With **Windows SDK Version** set to **7.0** and **Platform Toolset** set to **Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)** the same project builds successfully. [image: Snapshot showing that the project built fine with Windows SDK version 7 and Toolset v141_xp]

I understand there is a problem in my code, somewhere, but it is not showing any error in any code that belongs to the project I am building, it is only showing the error in the `list` header.

I want to find the culprit code that is causing this build failure.
What scenarios would make `list` give me these errors?

Why does it build fine with Windows SDK 7 and v141_xp toolset and, not with upgraded SDK and toolset?

Comment: *"What could be causing this?"* - Your code

Comment: Why didn't you just go to the line of code that is causing the issue?   More than likely you are violating C++ rules, but it is impossible to know without seeing your code.

Comment: @StoryTeller Lol. Thanks. It solved my problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is because the build output is not telling me where the problem is in my code. It showing me only two errors and both of them are in `list`, as in `Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\list`; and of course, I have no control over those files, I know something has changed in `std::list` but I am not able to figure out what it is, that I need to do to fix it, as I don't know which part of the code is doing that, and there are over 350 projects in this solution and so many dependencies between projects.

Comment: Y'know. I didn't leave a comment to make you feel stupid (yes, followed a twitter link). It really is impossible to help you with nothing but some screenshots and two lines of error message. @KateGregory may have edited your post, but that remained unchanged, "some folks" still see the same issue is there.

Comment: @StoryTeller No worries man!! I didn't take it personally, and on Twitter, that was just an expression out of frustration. By the way, If I had seen/found the code that is causing `list` to behave this way I would have posted it here. But those two lines of error messages were all I got. I have been working on to find the culprit code but still no luck yet.

Comment: @Abhishek
Were you able to fix this problem? I'm actually having something similar....

Answer (score 1):

Your project properties are possibly a red herring.

The error is that the type `std::pair<_Kty,_Ty>` has a deleted copy assignment operator, which can happen if various of its other constructors or assignment operators are explicitly defined or if the copy assignment operator is explicitly deleted.  While [std::list does not require T to be copy-assignable since c++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), you should perhaps double-check the `std::list`s that you are using in your program and see if you can make sure it's none of those that is leading up to this error.

To get better help you'll need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

(long comment converted into Answer)